# How to stop Monolog processing using a custom handler?

Tags: symfony, monolog

I am using `Monolog` in a `Symfony 2.8` project. I have configured a mail handler to send me notification about all errors.

Since not all errors are important (e.g. `PageNotFound` for `/apple-app-site-association`) I would like to add a filter. I did this by adding a custom Handler:

Config:

```
services:
    monolog.custom_handler.service:
        class: AppBundle\Log\CustomHandler

monolog:
    main:
        type: service
        id: monolog.custom_handler.service            
        level: error 
        handler: mail_buffer 
    mail_buffer:
        type:    buffer
        handler: mailer
    mailer:
        type:       swift_mailer
        from_email: "my address"
        to_email:   "my address"
        subject:    ERROR!
        formatter:  monolog.formatter.extended
```

Handler:

```
namespace AppBundle\Log;

use Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler;

class CustomHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    public function handle(array $record) {
        // Check if handling level was reached
        if ($record['level'] < $this->level) 
            return false;

        if (!empty($record)) {
            $url = (isset($record['extra']) && isset($record['extra']['url']) ? $record['extra']['url'] : '');
            $message = (isset($record['message']) ? $record['message'] : '');

            // Well Known Pages         
            if (strpos($url, '/.well-known') === 0) {
                //echo "...match 1</br>";
                return true;
            }

            if ($url == '/apple-app-site-association') {
                //echo "...match 2</br>";
                return true;
            }

            if (strpos($url, '/apple-touch-icon') === 0) {
                //echo "...match 3</br>";
                return true;
            }

            ...
        }

        // Record was NOT handled --> DO NOT stop bubbeling
        return false;
    }


}
```

Using the `echo` statements I can confirm, that the handler is called, and the `if` clause correctly matches. So, if `/apple-app-site-association` is called for example, the handler returns `true`. I would expect, that this stops bubbeling, and that thus the nested `mail_buffer` handler is NOT called anymore. **This is not the case.**

No matter if the handler return true or false, I still receive mail for all error.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I stop the processing of filtered messages?**

Comment: Have you tried with setting up levels for handlers?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The `main` handler is configured to level `error`. Thus all following handlers should only get messages of level `error` or height, shouldn't they? All `PageNotFound` errors are logged using the same level. So `/callToUnknownPage` has the same level as `/apple-app-site-association`, but the first should be logged while the second one should be skipped...

Comment: maybe other way - is it possible for You to inject there custom logger? Because if so then create other channel, custom handler for this channel that will send mails and you do not have to care about other errors.

Comment: This question is not about creating Monolog channels or injecting custom loggers. Error like `PageNotFound` are thrown on many different places I cannot control. I cannot inject a custom logger into core classes or third party bundles. Thus applying a custom filter to the log messages is my only option. Thus, this question is about how to apply a custom filter to log messages...

Comment: ok, this is why I was asking :) honestly - haven't had this kind of issue. If I were You I would try to run xdebug and see what is exactly happening. Sorry for not direct question-resolver.